# How to get a field from a List, with some input given

Tags: java, eclipse

In a Client-Server app, I have an ArrayList with some Files info (name, size, etc...): "file1.txt 0, file2.txt 3, etc...)"

How can i be able to get a size to a specific fileName?
I have a string that contains the fileName and i want the size of it.

```
      while (true) {
            Object obj = receiveMsg();

                if(((String) obj).contains(".txt")) {
                    for(String s : server.getFilesInfo()) {

                    }

                }
                System.out.println("Deal Client : Acabei de receber " + obj.toString());

            }

        }
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        disconnect();
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: If I get your question properly, you would like to print file name and it's size. On a string variable, you can invoke length() method to get the length of the file name. If you are looking for size of file, use this code. FileChannel fileChannel = FileChannel.open(filePath); long fileSize = fileChannel.size();

Comment: My client has a JList with all the files in the server. I choose one file, and a message is sent (to DealClient thread) with that fileName, and I want the respective size of that file. My problem is to get the specific size of the file. I know I can use lenght(), but how can I get the respective size?

Comment: if JList contains file names as string, then loop through the list and invoke length(). I don't know if I got your question properly

Comment: Imagine i give you a file Name, and I want you to give me the lenght of that file in particularly.

Comment: I am trying to understand your question again, does your list contain string like "file1.txt 0"? Here size of file1.txt is 0. is that what you need?

Comment: if the string i receive its caleed "file1.txt", then yes, 0 must be returned.

Comment: If that is the case, split the string with a space (" ") which gives you an array. first element becomes file name and second element is size. String[] tokens = i.split(" "); String fileName = tokens[0]; int length = Integer.valueOf(tokens[0]).